# MongoDB - most efficient way to query and project matching nested array object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My doc structure in "test" collection looks like below:

```
{
  "_id": "a1",
  "t": [
    {
      "tId": "t1",
      "do-not-project": "blah",
      "b": [
        {
          "bId": "b1",
          "name": "abc",
          "do-not-project": "blah"
        },
        {
          "bId": "b2",
          "name": "def",
          "do-not-project": "blah"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tId": "t2",
      "do-not-project": "blah",
      "b": [
        {
          "bId": "b3",
          "name": "ghi",
          "do-not-project": "blah"
        },
        {
          "bId": "b4",
          "name": "jkl",
          "do-not-project": "blah"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What's the most efficient way to query and project the below output if I know values for _id ("a1"), tId ("t2") and bId ("b3")? Aka only the matching nested array object and projected fields? Is this possible without aggregation at all?

```
{
  "_id": "a1",
  "t": [
    {
      "tId": "t2",
      "b": [
        {
          "bId": "b3",
          "name": "ghi"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), the find method has the following signature:

```
db.collection.find($query, $project)
```

So what you are looking for is probably something like:

```
db.collection.find(
    {_id: "a1", "t"."tId": "t2", "t"."b"."bId": "b3" },
    {"t"."tId": 1, "t"."b"."bId": 1, "t"."b"."name" :1}
)
```